# push a commit into multiple branches with git and netbeans

Tags: java, git, netbeans, git-commit, git-push

I need to push a commit into two or more branches as the same time, using Git and Netbeans. Those branches are not local, but in BitBucket and shared with others developers.

The situation is this: 
We have a branch which is used as a master (soon we will rebase it) and we are working on an another one. WHen I find a problem on the older branch, I'll switch to that and do the modification, then commit. I want the pushed code to be merged also with the newer branch.

How Can I do ?

Comment: It may help you to look at the BitBucket>Network Tree. What you want to do is merge the branch that you have the new commit/fix back into the project it came from. By doing this you should be able to get your network tree down to a single node to merge to master

Comment: Can you give me step to step guide ?

Comment: did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this, sounds to me like the simplest one in this case might be to use `git cherry-pick` to copy the commit from *old-branch* to *new-branch* locally on your machine, then push the revised *new-branch* back to Bitbucket.

The alternative way would be to create a PR on the server from *old-branch* to *new-branch*, whether or not this is viable will depend on what else is in *old-branch* that you don't want to copy across.

Comment: what is a PR ? (I'm noob and not english, sorry)

Comment: sorry, "Pull Request". This is a feature in Bitbucket that helps you merge code from one branch to another https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request. If you are _very_new to this, there is some good reading material on Atlassian's site, including a number of step-by-step guides!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. I tryed a cherry-pick trough Netbeans git plugin and it worked perfectly. Now just have to guess if it add only committed lines or if it merges the entire files in the pick. I'll do some tests. I'll try also the pull request, sooner or later.